# Is it possible to invoke functions without parentheses in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, package

I've been trying to make an internal package manager for my productivity (including other reasons). So I want the function to run when I type in to my code `pkg install particlesjs`. As far as I know the closest you can do is `pkg(install, particlesjs)`. Is there any way to make this possible in (Vanilla, No framework) JS?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call this function from a JavaScript source file, you will have to use `()`. This is the way to tell JavaScript "please run this function".

Calling just the function name will return the function as a variable, but in now way will it be executed.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thank you for the clarification

Comment: Some languages like Ruby can do what you're asking for. This is also the common way to run a program from the command line. Unfortunately JS does not have such a feature.